# Several Pattern extract from multiple CSV files

Tags: csv, perl

I'm new to programming, And I would like to wirte a code for below function in perl.

I have several CSV files (1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, 4.csv, .....), in every csv file where rows look like this:

```
<time, id1, id2, id3, filename> :

202008110100,10819066580072,2147858602,,Afile.txt
202008110110,12819066589761,,AC987678,Bfile.txt
202008110120,,8927489178,AC398761,Bfile.txt
202008110130,29274125780232,3829271910,AC119651,Cfile.txt
.
.
.
#id1,id2,id3 might be blank sometimes.
```

I have input like this :

```
<starttime,endtime,id1,id2,id3>:
#id1,id2,id3 might be **0**
eg):202008110105,202008110115,0,2147858602,0
```

If `id1`,`id2`,`id3` = 0, ignore the value,and only match for nonzero `id`.

And extract the `time` is during `starttime`and `endtime`.

And I'm expecting the match output like this :

```
1.csv:Afile.txt
```

Below is what I wrote, but it seems something wrong...Could someone help me ?

```
my $dir = <C:/Windows/Users/USER/Documents/Perlprogram>;
@files = ("1.csv","2.csv, 3.csv, 4.csv");

foreach $file (@files) {        
print "$file\n" if -f $file;
open(IN, "<./$file") or die("Error");
@before = <IN>;
close(IN);

@after = grep(/$greplist/, @before);
foreach $after (@after) {
print "$after\n";
}
sub after {
    $time = $_[6];
    if ($time >= $starttime and $time <=$endtime){
        open(OUT, ">>./search_result.txt");
        print($file,$_[4]);
        print(OUT $_[4]);
        close(OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where input data come from? File, STDIN or something else? Rewrite you question for clarification what you try to achieve. What is $dir variable for if you do not use it in your code? If you read data from a file then gave data sample as it appears in the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please [edit] your question and include what output or error messages you are getting right now. Also explain if it matters that there are different files. Do you need to interact with several of them at once? If not, that information is not relevant to your question. What about those IDs? Do you want to ignore the line if any of the three IDs is `0`? And what about `$dir`? That variable isn't used in your code.

Comment: Where do you define `$greplist`? Where do you call subroutine `after()`? Start your code with `use strict; use warnings;` and perl will assist you to eliminate a lot of mistakes.

Comment: I think you're missing the closing `}` for your first `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems something wrong...
>
> ```
> @files = ("1.csv","2.csv, 3.csv, 4.csv");
> ```

Aside from the grammar, the file names after the first are not properly quoted.

As Polar Bear noted, `$greplist` isn't defined. Assuming that it is set to what you call *input*, we can get the individual fields with

```
($starttime,$endtime,$id1,$id2,$id3) = split ',', $greplist;
```

The rest of the program is somewhat incoherent; you could replace the line `@before = <IN>;` with

```
    while (<IN>)
    {
        @_ = split ','; # split the CSV line to the values
        print $_[4] if  !$id1 || $_[1] == $id1
                    and !$id2 || $_[2] == $id2
                    and !$id3 || $_[3] == $id3
                    and $starttime <= $_[0]
                    and $_[0] <= $endtime
    }
```

and drop the other content of the `foreach $file` loop.